# Need help to read Excel file without installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I use the LINQ library to read data from excel file in my MVC Application, but it needs to be installed : Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

Is there any method to use LINQ without an installation of this Microsoft framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In case of Microsoft Excel 2007 or newer:*

These files (*.xlsx*) are in the **OpenXML** format which is a zip archive inside containing XML-formated files. You can extract this zip archive and use **LINQ to XML** to query data - but note, it will be a really raw data.

Alternatively, you should use a dedicated library provided by Microsoft: [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)

You don't need to install anything (e.g. MS Office) - just reference the library to the MVC project.

Then you can query data in a more user-friendly way with LINQ syntax too.

For example:

```
var refIndex = 7;
var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
var row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.RowIndex >= rowIndex);
```

Comment: @Carlos how did the LINQ with the Open XML SDK fit with your use-case?  Did it offer the sort of queries you were wanting?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is just a way to write queries from code.

Those queries will be translated by the provider, and executed by the datasource. The link from provider to datasource in this case is through OLEDB, using the Access engine to query Excel files. The machine that this code runs on, will have to have the Access Engine redistributable installed.

If you don't want that, you cannot use the approach you chose. You'll have to find another way to query Excel files. You could use a different library to read the Excel file, but then you'll have to find a library that offers querying - or reimplement that part yourself, using said library.